# How to plot only current day open on chart at end as line for NQ cash session?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
study("Open of first bar of a day")
// If start of the daily session changed, then it's first bar of the new session
isNewDay = time("D") != time("D")[1]
var firstBarCloseValue = open
if isNewDay
    firstBarCloseValue := open
plot(firstBarCloseValue)
```

Above code plots the series but i just want current day open like line extended to right not sure how i can achieve that. Any help appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `line()` for that.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var line l_open = na

// If start of the daily session changed, then it's first bar of the new session
isNewDay = time("D") != time("D")[1]

var firstBarCloseValue = open

if isNewDay
    firstBarCloseValue := open
    line.set_extend(l_open, extend.none)    // This at the moment points to the previous day's line. Do not extend it anymore as that day is over.
    l_open := line.new(bar_index, firstBarCloseValue, bar_index+1, firstBarCloseValue, extend=extend.right)
else
    line.set_x2(l_open, bar_index)
```

[image]

Comment: sorry @vitruvius solution you provided plots series of data which is line for all days open. I needed just open for last day. But please see i am looking for open of cash segment for futures. Normally open for futures give different opening. I am looking open price for NQ/ES for regular session and not extended session. Looking to get both open and close and plot it for last day and not all days. But appreciate your help.